# What is the correct and simplest way to check if a web service is available and not crash (windows phone 7)

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-7, exception

Can I just do this below? Or is there a more proper way to do it ?

```
    ServiceReferenceSLHS.HighScoreWSClient client = new ServiceReferenceSLHS.HighScoreWSClient();
        client.GetHighScoresCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReferenceSLHS.GetHighScoresCompletedEventArgs>(client_GetHighScoresCompleted);

        try
        {
            client.GetHighScoresAsync();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will only capture errors generated when calling the method `GetHighScoresAsync`. It's normally very unlikely that you'll have sure exceptions.

It's much more likley that you want to capture exceptions in the callback function (`client_GetHighScoresCompleted`).
Check the EventArgs there for errors.

Comment: But when I disconnect the NIC the error is deep within the web service proxy stuff... is there some sort of OnError callback ?  How do I keep it form crashing ?